# How can I click on 'Show more matches' on the Flashscore website using Selenium library in Python to scrape hidden information?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on scraping data from the Flashscore website.

https://www.flashscore.com/football/albania/superliga-2019-2020/results/

Although I can find the links for most of the matches that are visible once the above page loads, there are many matches that are hidden and can only be accessed by clicking on 'Show more matches'.
[Snapshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrgKF.png)

I found the class for 'Show more matches' (event__more event__more--static) and used the '.click()' method of the selenium library in Python but the output is null. Also, I tried various other implementations of clicking this link but couldn't get it working.

Is there any other way I can click on the link and extract the information in Python? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I also haven't found any classes where all of this information is hidden.

Comment: I tried this css selector `#live-table > div.event.event--results > div > div > a`, it did work

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide a Python code snippet of the same - since I have tried the same using selenium but the click didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the execute_script() driver method to achieve this. It's used for executing JavaScript in the current window/frame.

You can find the code snippet below-

```
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.com/football/albania/superliga-2019-2020/results/')
show_more_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="live-table"]/div[1]/div/div/a') #find the show more results element
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", show_more_button)
```